# Overriding a templated class function

Tags: c++, templates, callback

I'm trying to create some kind of callback for a class template. The code is like this:

```
template <typename t>
class Foo {
    void add(T *t) {
        prinf('do some template stuff');
        on_added(t);
    }
    void on_added(T *t) { }
}

struct aaa {}

class Bar : Foo<aaa> {
    void on_added(aaa *object) {
        printf("on added called on Bar");
    }
}
```

the on_added function on Bar never gets called. What would be the best way to add a callback  that a template subclass could optionally override? Thanks

Comment: Aren't you missing a virtual in front of your void on_added(...) in the base class?

Comment: Yes indee it works, thanks. Newb mistake, should I delete this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 'virtual'...

```
template <typename t>
class Foo {
    void add(T *t) {
        prinf('do some template stuff');
        on_added(t);
    }
    virtual void on_added(T *t) { }
}

struct aaa {}

class Bar : Foo<aaa> {
    void on_added(aaa *object) {
        printf("on added called on Bar");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your on_added function in Foo needs to be virtual.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the function `virtual` if you want calls in the base class to use the implementation in the derived class:

```
template <typename t>
class Foo {
    ...
    virtual void on_added(T *t) { }
};
```

Note that this is not special to templates, but applies to all classes.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone else has already answered the question. Let me just add that adding virtual functions breaks backward compatibility of the class. So, if this is a class that you control and there are no other dependent classes, then yes you can go ahead and convert the `on_added` to virtual, if not you need to make sure that the dependent modules are also rebuilt.